# Why does TestNG's implementation of assertEquals check both ways?

Tags: java, testng

I was checking to see how TestNG implements `assertEquals(Object, Object)` and found that at the lowest level, it's this:

```
private static boolean areEqualImpl(Object actual, Object expected) {
    if (expected == null && actual == null) {
        return true;
    } else if (expected != null && actual != null) {
        return expected.equals(actual) && actual.equals(expected);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What is the reason for the check `expected.equals(actual) && actual.equals(expected)`, when `expected.equals(actual)` alone should suffice?

Comment: junior developers tend to violate `#equals` contract.